# Python TypeError for NoneType Object

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am reading from a multi nested json file. I have created a class for getting specific keys from json and then create it into a dataframe.

Now if the keys are present everything works as expected and when the key is not found, I get the following error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Below is a sample json and the code snapshot

```
output = {"records":[{
    "ID":{
        "$":"123456"
    },
    "Records":{
        "ChildRecord":{
            "Address":[
                {
                    "$": "24 Street"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},{
    "ID":{
        "$":"456789"
    },
    "Records":{
        "ChildRecord":{
            "Address":[
                {
                    "$": "57 New Town"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}]}

identifier = [o.get('ID').get('$') for o in output['records']] 
address = [o.get('Records').get('ChildRecord').get('Address')[0].get('$') for o in output['records']]
print(identifier,'identifier')
print(address,'address')
```

Since the keys are present I get below output

```
identifier ['123456','456789'] 
address ['24 Street','57 New Town']
```

If the "Address" key is not present in one of the record then I get the type error, TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.
How to overcome this issue and get the output as

```
identifier ['123456','456789'] 
address ['24 Street',None]
```

Also, in some situation I get the address in multiple keys

```
"Address":[
                    {
                        "$": "57 New Town"
                    },
                    {   
                        "$": "New Castle Road"
                    },
                    {   
                        "$": "PO Box 309"
                    }
                ]
```

Is there a way to read the entire address as

```
['24 Street','57 New Town, New Castle Road, PO Box 309']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this part: `.get('Address')[0]` - when `Address` is not present, the `.get()` returns `None` and exception is thrown.

Here is slightly modified version that returns `None` if `Address` is not present (and not throw an error) **OR** joins the multiple addresses (if they are present):

```py
output = {
    "records": [
        {
            "ID": {"$": "123456"},
            "Records": {"ChildRecord": {"Address": [{"$": "24 Street"}]}},
        },
        {
            "ID": {"$": "456789"},
            "Records": {"ChildRecord": {}},
        },
    ]
}


identifier = [o.get("ID").get("$") for o in output["records"]]
address = [
    ", ".join(
        d["$"] for d in o.get("Records", {}).get("ChildRecord", {}).get("Address", [])
    )
    or None
    for o in output["records"]
]
print(identifier, "identifier")
print(address, "address")
```

Prints:

```
['123456', '456789'] identifier
['24 Street', None] address
```

---

It the `output` is

```py
output = {
    "records": [
        {
            "ID": {"$": "123456"},
            "Records": {"ChildRecord": {"Address": [{"$": "24 Street"}]}},
        },
        {
            "ID": {"$": "456789"},
            "Records": {
                "ChildRecord": {
                    "Address": [{"$": "57 New Town"}, {"$": "New Castle Road"}]
                }
            },
        },
    ]
}
```

Then the code prints:

```
['123456', '456789'] identifier
['24 Street', '57 New Town, New Castle Road'] address
```